# What does it mean to “offer a plea for a caution”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, expressions

This is a sentence in a letter to request waiving a fine. The sentence is:

> I offer the following plea for a caution in this instance.

Also, it seems to me that *caution* is more correct than *a caution*. Am I right?

Comment: http://onelook.com/?w=caution&ls=a "caution (n) an official warning from the police"

Comment: Though the question may be justified, it would have helped if the OP had first looked up *caution* in a dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give [a caution](https://www.gov.uk/caution-warning-penalty) is (in Britain at least) to let someone go with a warning instead of (in this case) having to pay a fine

> Cautions are given to adults aged 18 or over for minor crimes - eg writing graffiti on a bus shelter.
>
> You have to admit an offence and agree to be cautioned. If you don’t agree, you can be arrested and charged.
>
> A caution is not a criminal conviction, but it could be used as evidence of bad character if you go to court for another crime.

So *a plea to give a caution* is a suggestion to change the fine to a lesser punishment  and the [plea](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/plea) contains the arguments to support this change

Not to be confused with
*A plea for caution* which is a request made in an urgent manner to make people aware of a dangerous situation

Comment: Is it meant warning By `caution`?

Comment: @SinaIravanian Only in as much as it's a warning not to get into trouble again.